# Neo4j cypher: Store timestamp as a node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When trying to store a timestamp `localdatetime()` as node property `updatedAt`:

```
MERGE (profile:Profile {userId:{id}})
      SET profile += {userId:{id}, updatedAt:localdatetime()}
      RETURN profile
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Current record format does not support TEMPORAL_PROPERTIES. 
Please upgrade your store to the format that support requested capability.
```

I'm running Neo4j `3.4.4` as a Docker container, version, so this error shouldn't be occurring. Is my cypher query wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with:

Removing all nodes: 
`MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;`

Removing all graph.db labels and properties:
`sudo rm -rf neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/*.*`

Comment: That suggests this was an issue where a Neo4j upgrade took place, but a store upgrade wasn't performed.